# Declaring & Calling The Sleep API

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have read many threads on implementing the Sleep API however most are a step ahead of where I am at in terms of knowledge to some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have a macro in VBA which I would like to add pauses to, between steps (purely aesthetic rather than functional) however I am struggling with the basic declaring and calling.

I understand that first I must declare the api and that the code for this is...

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

however, I am confused with regards to where this should go. Should it go in a module of it's own or can it be stated at the top of the macro module?

Then to call the function do I simply add a line to the macro of...

```
Call Sleep (1000)
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone can help with this question and appreciate your patience with my basic grasp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration of Sleep should go to the top of a module. Standard coding module.

You can omit `Call` and just use

```
Sleep 1000  ' 1 second delay
```

anywhere within an existing sub, so

```
Option Explicit

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub Main()

    ' wait 3 seconds
    Sleep 3000

End Sub
```

[image]

---

an alternative without declaring the Sleep sub would be

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03") ' waits 3 seconds
```

Comment: I have never had to use sleep in MS Access. I wonder is the OP using an odd approach?

Comment: not sure but the question is quite specific the OP claims he wants to use `Sleep`

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. Took a bit of fiddling but I got it in there. This has uncovered another challenge for me though but I think that requires a separate question if I am understanding this forum correctly so will post separately. Really appreciate the support. Cheers

Comment: @spcurtis81 yes good way of thinking but it's not a forum but a questions and answers site :) If you feel happy with the answers given you can accept them with a green check mark it's like marking your original problem as solved.

Comment: @mehow Ah ha. Was wondering how I marked that answer as correct. Oh so simple when you find it. Must say considering my novice understanding, I was a bit nervous about asking questions in such a knowledgeable community so the response and understanding is much appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you end up with a black background in your VBA environment