# how to capture real time data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have a cell (A1) linked to real-time data (=Tickers!Z12). i want to capture all of the price range in a five minute period. my issue is i'm trying to use the Worksheet_Change method but it wont update when the values change if the cell (A1)  is formulated. it works fine if i manually change the values. but i need to capture values that are being generated by the formula and then copy & paste the values in column B everytime the values change. here's what i have so far.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False

 If Range("A1").value <> Range("B2").value Then
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    With ActiveSheet
      LastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1
      .Cells(LastRow, 2).Select
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

 End If

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Does anything in [this thread](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/151347-Sheet-Change-Event-doesn-t-fire) help? Or [this one](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=57855)? What have you tried, what has/hasn't worked?

Comment: what causes the formula in A1 to recalculate?

Comment: What is causing the data in cell Tickets!Z12 to refresh? Do you use automatic refresh option?

Comment: i'm using a dde link to retrieve real-time data on a different worksheet(Tickers) and i just link to it by =Tickers!Z12. i'm unsure how to recalculation is handled through the dde link .

Comment: I would suggest not to use worksheet_change. Try writing a Timer procedure that checks every 30 seconds (or so) if the value in cell A1 is not the value in cell B1. All the rest you already have in place.

Comment: my issue with a time procedure is that i need all the values in a 5 minute interval so i can determine the min & max price range. if i refresh lets say every 30 seconds the data would be inaccurate. however, i could refresh lets say every 1 second , but then my concern is how that will affect the performance of the workbook. and ideas?

Comment: I agree, timing is not the solution here. Try the calculate event, see if that works for you. See my answer.

Comment: Refreshing every second could have unwanted affect. If you do choose it, make sure you implement DoEvents otherwise Excel could just freeze. Since we don't know exactly how your dde link works, try detecting the right event. Perhaps worksheet_calculate as vacip suggested. If you can't find the event you will eventually have to use Timer/Sleep methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Worksheet_Calculate event.

Also, I'm not sure you want to compare A1 to B2. Logic dictates you should be comparing it to the last cell in column B.

Also, using Activesheet is not a good idea, as the recalculation can happen when you are on any other sheet, and you don't want to write values on random worksheets.

And one more thing: don't use copy-paste ina  macro. Just make .Value=.Value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim lngLastRow As Long

On Error Goto SkipAllThis

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

With Worksheets("Source") 'or whatever sheet has your code and stores your values
  lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  If .Range("A1").Value <> .Cells(lngLastRow, 2).Value Then
    .Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 2).Value = Range("a1").Value
  End If
End With

SkipAllThis:

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: its not reacting to the real-time changes and its not capturing all of the values in column B. its just overwriting the values in column B, where i need the changed values to be captured in the next empty row. does that make sense? so everytime the value changes its entered in the last row of column b.

Comment: by revising the code to this. i have achieved the capture order i desire but i still cant get it to automatically capture the values when they change.    lngLastRow = Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Comment: @drs Strange, it does collect values below each other for me. 0_o

Comment: @drs Hmm, can you try putting a code on worksheet "Tickers" and test events `Calculate` and `Change`, to see if any one of those trigger when the dde link gets refreshed?

Comment: out of curiosity i tried to run it under worksheet_change, and i linked the A1 cell (=E1) so i can manually input & change the values in E1 and its working perfectly, but when i link to the cell (=abc123|tik!id0?last) that retrieves the data from its api source theres no reaction to any changes to that cell. is there anyway to trigger an event everytime the data changes from its api source?

Comment: markets have closed so my real-time data is no longer available i will have to wait till tomorrow to continue. but i will try to setup the change on the tickers page to see what happens. THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP!

Comment: ok, after messing around with it. its sorta working. here's the issue now. when the workbook opens up i get runtime error 13 type mismatch. this happens because the A1 cell is returning N/A# until the api connection is established which takes a few seconds. as a result the sheet quits unless i F8 through the code once and then it will reset and run properly. any thoughts on how to handle the error? any way to get the worksheet_calculate to pause for a few seconds when the work book opens?

Comment: I have added an On Error statement, which practically skips the code in case of an error. It is important though to turn `calculations` and `screenupdating` back on if they were turned off. Try this, see if it works. Also, if you made any changes, tell me, so that I can update the code to better help future googlers.

Comment: @drs I'm glad it worked out. It was an interesting problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

DRS,

Implement the sleep function as:

[Declaring & Calling The Sleep API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325958/declaring-calling-the-sleep-api)

Then afterward, capture your value.  Just note the API is in milliseconds.

G.