# Oracle parallel query returns before actual job finishes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, vb6, ado

A VB 6 program is processing records and inserting in a temporary table, then these records are moved from this temporary table to actual table as

```
connection.Execute "INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE"
```

The temporary table is then truncated when records are moved

```
connection.Execute "TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE"
```

This is working fine untill I use PARALLEL hint for INSERT query. I receive this error on TRUNCATE

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout
>   expired

It looks to me that parallel query returns before completing the job and TRUNCATE command is issued causing the lock.

I checked the number of records inserted as below and found that it is far less than the number of records in temporary table

```
connection.Execute "INSERT /*+ PARALLEL */ INTO MAIN_TABLE SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE", recordsAffected
```

Is there any way to wait for INSERT to complete?

Comment: What's your connection string? Can you specify a longer timeout?

Comment: Do a `Delete` rather than `Truncate`. But if this is just a temp table, why do you need to delete at all? `ON COMMIT {DELETE | PRESERVE} ROWS` will empty the table after each commit | session.

Comment: @dbmitch It is not about TIMEOUT, but connection.Execute returns which causes next query to be executed while first one is still under process

Comment: @topshot DELETE will be slower and transactional while TRUNCATE wont, the temporary table is not Oracle's temp table, it is an actual physical table, there is another process which checks correctness of records and then move is performed

Comment: Again...what's your connection string?

Comment: @dbmitch `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myuser;Password = mypass;Data Source=mysource;`

Answer (score 0):

> This assumes you're using ADO - though I now notice you don't have
>   that tag in your question.

Can you monitor the connection state with a loop waiting for executing to finish?

Something like

> **EDIT - Fix Boolean Add to use + instead of "AND"**

```
While Conn.State = (adStateOpen + adStateExecuting)
   DoEvents
   Sleep 500 ' uses Sleep API command to delay 1/2 second
Wend
```

[Sleep API declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325958/declaring-calling-the-sleep-api)

> **Edit - Add Asynch Hint/Option**

Also - it might help the ADO connection to give it a hint that its running asynchronously, by adding the `adAsyncExecute` to end of your execute command

ie. Change the execute sql command to look like

```
conn.execute sqlString, recordsaffected, adAsyncExecute
```

Comment: What does that mean? It has an error, it never ends or it exits loop immediately?

Comment: I fixed the loop condition - apparently using AND doesn't add the bits properly - both values must be set, so simply adding them together will result in the proper condition

Comment: This time it is waiting but I don't know yet that it is waiting till the end of job because I am still receiving the same resource busy error.

Answer (score 0):

`Delete` may be slower but `Truncate` is DDL which you can't run at the same time as DML. In fact, `Truncate` requires exclusive access to the table. DML on tables will request a share mode lock on the table which means you can't do DDL against the table at the same time.

A possible alternate solution would be to use synonyms. You have your table A 
and a synonym S pointing to A

```
create table B as select * from A where 1=0; 
create or replace synonym S for B
```

Your app now uses B instead of A so you can do what you want with A.

Do this every time you want to "truncate"

Comment: I haven't tried this but what if INSERT and DELETE are running in parallel? won't it DELETE the rows which have not been copied yet?

Comment: If you have no criteria on which to select what to delete I'm sure it could. If they are from other sessions and not committed yet then it wouldn't. If you were allowed to do `truncate`, it would do the same thing though. Either way, if you are trying to get more speed by running your statements in parallel, you're going to have to figure out how to deal with the conflicts. So you `INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE some_key {<, between, ...}` and then have the same `WHERE` clause on your delete.