# MS-Access: Populate modal form from custom type

Tags: ms-access, modal-dialog, custom-type

I am trying to display an error form, populated with text from a custom type object, as a MS-Access version of the fantastic answer on [this Excel question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028288/properly-handling-errors-in-vba-excel).

The problem I run into is that I want to wait for a user response/confirmation on this error form, so it must be (as far as I am aware) a modal form and therefore I cannot just open the form and immediately populate it.

I have tried to find a way of doing in Access what was done in Excel; load the form, populate the form then display the form, but this doesn't seem possible since Access' event order is Open->Load->...

I have also tried looking for a way to open as a normal form, populate and then 'modalise' the form but could not find a way to do this.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this function? Or is there an alternative to modal forms to pause execution awaiting user input?

Comment: I open forms with acDialog parameter of OpenForm method. This suspends code execution from the calling form until the dialog form closes.

Comment: Also, I pass parameters to the dialog form via OpenArgs and then dialog form manipulates itself with its own code.

Comment: I had the terminology wrong for modal vs. dialog. My code is indeed using OpenForm with acDialog, but this is blocking me from populating the form before the user sees it. Passing parameters via OpenArgs would work, but my parameters are not strings so I don't believe I can send them directly.

Comment: Well, acHidden can open form not visible but I don't see any way to set form as Dialog after it is opened. What kind of response is required by the user? MsgBox or InputBox could not serve instead of form?

Comment: see my post below. You can open the form as hidden, set all the controls you want. You then execute a openform on the "already" open form as dialog - the form is now dialog and waits for user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modal form is VERY different from a dialog form.

Modal forms do NOT cause the calling code to halt, but a dialog form does.
(do not confuse the two types of forms).

To “get back” a user response from a dialog form, simply set the form visible = false in place of a close form command. This will KICK the dialog form out of dialog mode, and your calling code now continues and the calling code is “free” to examine any values the user typed in or say choose from combo boxes, or check boxes, or whatever.

So your code block will look like this:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

   Dim f       As String
   Dim strT    As String

   f = "formB"
   DoCmd.OpenForm f, , , , , acDialog

   If CurrentProject.AllForms(f).IsLoaded Then
      ' grab any values entered by user, or whatever buttons hit
      strT = Forms(f).Text1
      ' etc. etc. etc. - grab values from that form
      ' don't forget to close the form
      DoCmd.Close acForm, f
   Else
      ' user canceled the form
      ' code goes here for user hitting your cancel button or "x"
   End If

End Sub
```

And in your dialog form, the “ok” button, or “close” button simply goes:

Me.visible = False

If the user hits your cancel button, that code would be:

Docmd.Close acForm

So if the user hits “cancel” or even the “X” in the upper right corner, you consider and assume the user “bailed out”. When they do this, the form will be closed.

So the code after the dialog part simply checks if the form is STILL open (because your “ok” button does a visible = false).

And since the form is STILL open, then you are free to grab the values of ANY control – say user text typed into a text box, values from a combo box, check box, or whatever.

When user is done the calling code is free to examine or grab any value(s) from that form.

**Edit - 2nd solution to allow "setting" of values.**

This code will work:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

   Dim f       As String
   Dim strT    As String

   f = "formB"

   DoCmd.OpenForm f
   Forms(f).Text1 = "Hello"    ' set values on form

   ' now WAIT for user   
   Do While CurrentProject.AllForms(f).IsLoaded
      If Forms(f).ok = True Then Exit Do
      DoEvents
   Loop

   If CurrentProject.AllForms(f).IsLoaded Then
       If Forms(f).ok = True Then
          MsgBox "value return = " & Forms(f).Text1
       Else
          MsgBox "user cancel"
       End If
       DoCmd.Close acForm, f
   Else
      ' cancel code goes here
      MsgBox "user cancel"
   End If

End Sub
```

The code for the OK button on the form B is now:

```
Me.Visible = False
Me.ok = True
```

And you need a public var "ok" in form B.
eg this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public ok      As Boolean
```

So the cancel button in form B can simply close the form. (you can close the form - but don't set ok = True)

Comment: Thank you for the description, I've used this format elsewhere. What I'm left struggling with in this case is that I would like to populate controls on the dialog box before the user sees it. Since code immediately halts I can't populate after opening the form. I suppose I could hide the form in its on-load event and then make it visible again when I have populated it.

Comment: My code does exactly that. I first open the form "invisible" as non dialog. I am free to load up and set any control on the form as my code and my example shows. You then execute a opeform again with a dialog mode for the code to wait. Look close at my explain, and at my code. I set control values in the form after I open it (but I open the form as invisible). When I execute the open form again on the already open form, it is now in dialog mode and the code waits until the user hits ok. Read my post again, and read my code again - it does exactly as you ask and allows you to set any control.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the second DoCmd.OpenForm. 
I just tried this method but found it didn't work, the second DoCmd.OpenForm isn't stopping execution.

Comment: You are 100% correct - my example does NOT work. See my updated code snip. It works quite well.

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I wanted. I did have to make the form modal (I think I'm using that correctly this time) to prevent the user just clicking away from the error form.

Comment: You will want a `Sleep 50` or so in the `Do While` loop, to avoid high processor load. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325958/declaring-calling-the-sleep-api @S.Meredith

Comment: I do recommend the "sleep" 50 idea, but you need a sleep function. The code as "posted" does work fine, but it does spin the CPU up to near max while that form is "open" and the loop code is spnning and waiting. Today most computers have multiple cores and threads - so it not the end of the world or so bad as in the old days with only one CPU on a computer - today that is rare, and thus you can quite much live with the code as is. However, I will concede that as a developer, a wait of 50 mil secs or even 100 is a good idea.  And as per posters notes - the form should be modal.