# Can "docmd.runcmd accmdnewobject..." be delayed until the object has been defined?

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

I have a VBA procedure that uses

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectDesignTable
```

to create a table.  When the table is defined it then uses

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectForm
```

to create a form based on the table previously created.

How to delay creatng the form until after the table has been defined?

It was suggested that I check for the existence of the TDF after running DoCmd to define the table.  The questions still is:  How to delay checking until after DoCmd completes?

While VBA is not multi-threaded, "DoCmd" is.

You can get the name by comparing AllTables before and after the create.

Comment: https://sodocumentation.net/access-vba/topic/7384/check-if-table-exists-in-current-db

Comment: VBA isn't multi-threaded, so there shouldn't be a problem. There is [Sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325958/declaring-calling-the-sleep-api) but I doubt you need it here. Please show full code that reproduces the problem.